# identify equal named functions from different additional dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, include

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio where libs (oldVersion.lib, newVersion.lib) are added via project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Both libs contain the same function (e.g. `foo()`). The functions are included by their header files and called via `::foo()`.

The code itself does not show an error but at runtime it is not clear if `foo()` from oldVersion or newVersion is executed.

Is it possible to differentiate between same named functions from the two different .libs? ([Like `aliases` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759726/net-multiple-libraries-with-the-same-namespace-referencing))

What I tried:

- [Wrapping external libraries in namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626211/wrapping-external-libraries-in-namespaces) 
  Not working because in line `coollib_coolthing(howcool);` it is not clear where `howcool` (which would be `foo`) comes from.
- ```
  namespace newVersion{
  #inlcude "newVersion.h"
  }
  ```

  Here, the `newVersion` namespace is added to the information from the .h file but `newVersion::foo()` still executes the first `foo` it can find somewhere.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to distinguish directly. I suggest that you could encapsulate one of the static libraries. Create a new static library and wrap the existing static library. You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati).

Comment: Thanks @BarrnetChou for the reply. That seems to be a working and easy way to do it. I'll give it try.

Comment: If there are any questions during your attempt, welcome to ask again. I am pleased to help you.

Comment: The comments in your referenced solution state [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678312/13870112) I am running into, atm.
I can now call `wrapper::foo()` from wrapper.lib but as the new lib links the old ones, the linker again has to decide between `foo()` functions from original .libs at some point.
Do you know how I can achieve "The wrapper [...] should not export the offending symbol" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for that I should provide a better plan rather than a complicated method.

Here is the method: Just tell the linker that the symbols in a library are known by some other name and use that name. You need to make a [def](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=vs-2019) file and provide the name translation in the [EXPORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=vs-2019) section. The process would be to make a def file for one of the libraries then use this def file to build a lib file and then link with that lib file.

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati/678312#678312) for more information about this method which is provided by Jim Monte.

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well.
Additionally, my .lib linked a .dll. After changing the functions names in the .lib they weren't found in the .dll anymore.
I ended up opening the .dll with an editor and changed its names (important: new names have to be of same length than original name) there. Then [created a .lib from .dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127548/13870112).